# SDL_Texture not rendering properly

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm making a game board with a 3D array which stores the location of items (a  vector of Items for each **descrete** x,y position on the game board). Each item type (Subclass of Item) has an associated sprite, which is stored as a Texture. The code for storing the textures is given  below

```
void render(){
        int x = 0;
        //for each row in the array
        for(vector<vector<Item*>> row : items){
            int y = 0;
            // for each column in the row
            for(vector<Item*> col : row){
                //Graphical positons
                int pos_x = x * CELL_WIDTH;
                int pos_y = y * CELL_HEIGHT;

                //Initalise the rectangle
                SDL_Rect rect;
                rect.x = pos_x;
                rect.y = pos_y;
                rect.w = CELL_WIDTH;
                rect.h = CELL_HEIGHT;
                // if the the list of items is empty
                

                if(col.size() > 0){
                    for(Item* item: col){
                        SDL_Texture *texture = NULL; 
                        texture = textureMap[item->typestring];
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0 ,0, 0);
                        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, &rect);
                        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                    
                    }

                }
                else{
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);

                }
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                y++;
                
            }
            x++;
            
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        
    }
```

but none of the sprites render and there is a blank screen. worth mentioning that if the code which attempts to fill rect with the sprite is changed to just show a colored square, it works :

```
        void render(){
        int x = 0;
        //for each row in the array
        for(vector<vector<Item*>> row : items){
            int y = 0;
            // for each column in the row
            for(vector<Item*> col : row){
                //Graphical positons
                int pos_x = x * CELL_WIDTH;
                int pos_y = y * CELL_HEIGHT;

                //Initalise the rectangle
                SDL_Rect rect;
                rect.x = pos_x;
                rect.y = pos_y;
                rect.w = CELL_WIDTH;
                rect.h = CELL_HEIGHT;
                // if the the list of items is empty
                

                if(col.size() > 0){
                    for(Item* item: col){
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 100, 100, 0);
                        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                
                    }

                }
                else{
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);

                }
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
                y++;
                
            }
            x++;
            
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        
    }
```

results in this game screen, with grey squares in the positions the items should be in

[image]

here is the code for creating textures from .png filepath string stored in each class, and storing it in a Map<String,SDL_Texture>.

```
            for(vector<vector<Item*>> row : items){
            for(vector<Item*> col : row){
                for(Item* item: col){
                    if(textureMap.find(item->typestring) == textureMap.end()){

                        SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
                        SDL_Surface* temp = IMG_Load(item->imgpath);
                        
                        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, temp);
                        SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
                        textureMap.insert({item->typestring, texture});
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        }
```

I'm new to C++ and SDL2, can anyone see any obvious issues with the way the SDL_Textures are being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using                         `SDL_RenderFillRect` after `SDL_RenderCopy`.

`SDL_RenderCopy` does what you want to get a texture on screen. But `SDL_RenderFillRect` will fill an area with a colour. If you do the copy before the fill in the same spot, the colour will be overwritting the texture.

Just remove `SDL_RenderFillRect` and the texture should appear properly.